# What is $\circeq$ used for?

Tags: notation

I was looking for a way to put 'des' over the equals sign in latex and stumbled upon this symbol

$\circeq$

What are mathematicians using it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search shows a few uses of $\circeq$ to represent a binary relation. Examples:

> If $\Sigma, \Delta$ are sets of sentences, say that
>   $\Sigma \circeq \Delta$ iff they have the same models.

and

> Let $\circeq$ be the relation on the set $P(\mathbb R)$ of all polynomials with real coefficients defined by $f \circeq g$ iff $f$ and $g$ have a root in common.

The character is also known as ["ring equal to"](https://codepoints.net/U+2257?lang=en).